# HTML Picture coding

Tags: html, css, image

I was wondering. I see the favicons on the website tab in my browser, and was wondering how to do this for my website also. If you don't know what I'm talking about, just look at the picture.[image]

Comment: FYI: These are called "favicons"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, just add:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

in your html head elements.

Comment: Actually, I found that it still works in between the '<html>' and '<body>' tags. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html 
      PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en-US">
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="http://example.com/myicon.png">
[…]
</head>
[…]
</html>
```

The `<link>` tag is where you configure the icon.

[This link should help you with what your looking for.](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon)

Comment: Link answers are generally discouraged.  You may get downvoted for this.  Try explaining what to do instead of just linking to some page.